# How do get Sympy (in python) to plug in a given value for a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, sympy, taylor-series

So I am currently in Calculus 2 and we recently began talking about Taylor Series (yay....), becuase its a natoriously hard topic, my teacher recomended we write a programing code that is able to do Taylor Series in order to better understand the mechanics. So far this has really helped and I was able to get it to find the 4 deritives but I am not sure how to get it to plug in the correct C value into the function and the 4 deritives. Can someone show me what do do next? Thanks:

```
import sympy as sy
sy.init_printing()

H=0

#Variables
while H!=100:
    
    x=sy.symbols("x")
    f=(input('Please enter function, x '))
    c=int(input('Enter the center of the equasion, c '))

    #Derivatives
    dx=sy.Derivative(f)
    dx=dx.doit()
    Dx=sy.Derivative(dx)
    Dx=Dx.doit()
    DX=sy.Derivative(Dx)
    DX=DX.doit()
    D_X=sy.Derivative(DX)
    D_X=D_X.doit()
    H=H+1
    print('The First Deritive, is:')
    print(dx)
    print('The Second Deritive, is:')
    print(Dx)
    print('The Third Deritive, is:')
    print(DX)
    print('The Fourth Deritive, is:')
    print(D_X)
```

Comment: Taylor series are great fun.  Few people realize that when your processor does an `fsin` instruction, it's actually using a Taylor series to compute the result.

Comment: That's actually pretty interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to point out that `d1x`, `d2x`, `d3x` and `d4x` would be much better names than `dx`, `Dx`, `DX`, and `D_X`.

```
    print('The First derivative, is:')
    print(dx)
    print(f'The value of the first derivative at {c} is:')
    print(dx.subs(x,c))
    print('The Second derivative, is:')
    print(Dx)
    print(f'The value of the second derivative at {c} is:')
    print(Dx.subs(x,c))
    print('The Third derivative, is:')
    print(DX)
    print(f'The value of the third derivative at {c} is:')
    print(DX.subs(x,c))
    print('The Fourth derivative is:')
    print(D_X)
    print(f'The value of the fourth derivative at {c} is:')
    print(D_X.subs(x,c))
```

Comment: Fair enough, but how do I get it to plug c into stuff?

Comment: Oh I see now, sorry misread that lol. Thanks so much my guy!